# POST text/plain from a file using the Fetch API

Tags: http, file-upload, fetch-api

I need to send a file from a HTML page using a POST `text/plain` HTTP request.  **NOT** a `multipart/form-data`.

I can use the following to POST a singlepart `text/plain`:

```js
fetch('/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    body: 'The content of the singlepart text/plain.',
});
```

With an `<input type="file" id="file">` in a form, I can POST it in multipart like this:

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
fetch('/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
});
```

But I cannot seem to send a singlepart HTTP `text/plain` with the content of the file as the only content in the request body.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is as simple as this:

```js
fetch('/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    body: document.getElementById('file').files[0],
});
```

I got confused, because the Firefox Network inspector displayed the following:

```
No payload for this request
```

But I do receive it on the server.